# Entity Framework: Generate custom Id for MYSQL table

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I need to generate a custom ID (a number sequence prefixed with a string) using the Entity Framework for a MYSQL table. The following example illustrates what is needed

```
Id            name
ACT-DT-1      Activity DT
ACT-Dx-1      Activity Dx
ACT-Dx-2      Activity Dx
ACT-DT-2      Activity DT
ACT-DT-3      Activity DT
```

so if the new record is an ACT-Dx the Id must be ACT-Dx-3, OR if it is a ACT-DT the Id must be ACT-DT-4, OR else if it has a new prefix e.g. ACT-Dg the Id must be ACT-Dg-1.

What is the best approach that I can take,

Comment: More information is needed.  I'm not clear what makes a record a ACT-Dx record or a ACT-Dg record.  Are you just basing this on the 10th character in the name?

Comment: Yes, it is based on the name (I have updated the example to clarify)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you override `SaveChanges` method of your DbContext. Not sure if this is the best practice but it is working in one of my projects.

The principle is, that when you add a new entity to your dbContext, you assign fake IDs with values -1, -2, -3 etc. Those fake keys get replaced by proper key values when executing `SaveChanges` calling `ReplaceIDs` method.

Doing this you must of course update references in another related entities. It may be tricky if you name your foregn keys differently then your primary keys. I allways try to have the same names for foreign and primary keys, not using just `ID` but `ActivityID`.

This is a quickly modified version, hope it does not contain mistakes.

```
public partial class MyDbContext 
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        // Other custom logic          
        ReplaceIDs();          
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces IDs with calculated values when saving
    /// </summary>
    private void ReplaceIDs()
    {
        Debug.Print("**************************************************************");
        this.ObjectContext.DetectChanges();
        foreach (var dbEntityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added))
        {
            Type t =  GetEntityType(dbEntityEntry.Entity);
            string baseTypeName = t.Name;

            // Get the entity key name
            var keyName = this.ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace
                            .GetEntityContainer(this.ObjectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace)
                            .BaseEntitySets
                            .First(x => x.ElementType.Name.Equals(baseTypeName))
                            .ElementType
                            .KeyMembers
                            .Select(key => key.Name)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

            string keyValue = null;  
            if (keyName!=null)
            {
                keyValue = dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues[keyName]; 
            }

            string newKey = null;

            //Custom logic for ID replacement
            if (t.Name.Equals("MyTable") && keyValue!= null)
            {
                string addedName = dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues["Name"];
                int keyValueNumber;  
                if (keyValue.HasValue && Int32.TryParse(keyValue, out keyValueNumber) && keyValueNumber <= 0) 
                {
                    //Calculate shomehow the last value of your set of IDs
                    //I store last IDs for different sets in extra table, e.g. IDSets  
                    var q = from x in this.IDSets where x.Name.Equals(addedName) && x.TableName.Equals("MyTable")
                            select x.LastID;
                    var lastKey = q.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (lastKey == null) throw new Exception("..."); //Handle somehow missing ID set, create new etc.
                    int? newID = null;
                    if (lastKey.LastID  == null)
                       newID=1;
                    else
                       newID= lastKey.LastID;
                    newKey = string.Format("{0}-{1}",addedName,++newID);                        
                    lastKey.LastID = newID;  
                }
            }

            //Key replacement
            if (newKey!=null)
            {
                int originalKey = (int)dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues[keyName];
                dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues[keyName] = newKey;

                Debug.Print("{0},{1} = {2} : {3}", baseTypeName, addedKontext, newKey, newIDWithKontext);

                //Refresh references
                string keyNameHelper=String.Format("{0}_", keyName);
                foreach (var e in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
                {
                    Type tfix = e.Entity.GetType().BaseType;
                    foreach (var pname in e.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
                    {
                        if ((pname.Equals(keyName) || pname.StartsWith(keyNameHelper)))
                        {
                            object o = e.CurrentValues[pname];
                            if (o!=null && o.GetType() == typeof(Int32) && ((int)o) == originalKey)
                            {
                                e.CurrentValues[pname] = newKey;
                                Debug.Print("FIX: {0},{1} = {2} >> {3}",tfix.Name, pname, originalKey, newKey);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        this.ObjectContext.DetectChanges();
        Debug.Print("**************************************************************");
    }


    public static Type GetEntityType(object entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            return null;
        if (IsProxy(entity))
            return entity.GetType().BaseType;
        else
            return entity.GetType();
    }
```

Comment: My question is, when the application is used by multiple users will this solution guarantee that the same id will not be accessed at the same time?

Comment: I use this with database replicas, so I have allways assigned the ID range that can be used by particular replica. In multi-user-one -database scenario there is a slight chance of having duplicate IDs if SaveChanges occurs exactly at the same moment.